# jQuery print plugins printing wrong selected values

Tags: jquery, printing

I have tried all jQuery libraries specially, printElement,print and PrintArea. All these libraries gives the same output which is incorrect. Below is the demo on fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ovy11s1q/

My html code is :

```
    <div id="printDiv">Drop Down:
        <select name="selectInput" id="selectInput">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3" selected>3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" name="Print" id='printDivButton' value="Print">Click to print !</button>
 </div>
```

My javascript code is:

```
    $('#printDivButton').click(function () {
        $("#printDiv").print();
    });
```

When I select 4 it gives correct print out but when I select 2 it gives wrong print.

**I don't want to modify any of the libraries but want an workaround !**

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, you can try that :

```
$('#selectInput').on('change', function() {
    var v = this.value;
    $('#selectInput option').removeAttr('selected');
    $("#selectInput option[value="+v+"]").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
$('#printDivButton').click( function() {
   $("#printDiv").print();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Kénium, but this is changing my source. I am not allowed to change the existing source.

Comment: Your given code is not working on any version of IE :(